# mysql float storage size?

Tags: mysql, floating-point

On the mysql docs it states that a `float` column uses,

```
float(p) = 4 bytes if 0 <= p <= 24, 8 bytes if 25 <= p <= 53
```

So does this mean that if my column is expressed as below

```
float(20, 6)
```

Then does `p` equal to the amounts added? So in the above example it would be a total size of 8 bytes as `20 + 6 == 26`.

Or does it mean that p is equal to 20 so that it would be a storage size of 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

p is equal 20, yes. The 6 is how much digits after the semicolon/dot there are.

I.e. `decimal(5,2)` means, that values in this column can range from -999.99 to 999.99

You can read more about it in the [manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

It means that p is equal to 20 as that is the number of significant digits which are held.  The second number represents the number of digits which can be stored after the decimal point.

It's mentioned on [enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) just below the example.